# is there a filter to seperate glycerol and biodiesel?

Tags: fuel, filtering

i am currently working on a project of manufacturing biodiesel from cooking oils by the process "TRANSESTERIFICATION". at the end of this reaction, after the reaction mixture settles I have two layers 1. biodiesel on top 2.glycerol at the bottom. manually the separation can be done by a separating funnel but is there a way by which I could automate the separation process of this mixture?

Comment: What is the scale You are doing this? If You do it on a serious scale, you can use a separator. If You play around, buy a 5l separating funnel. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separator_(Verfahrenstechnik) The english page is very poor.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

From this: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0961-9534(01)00074-5

And this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycerol

Apparently most bodiesels have a BP of 340-375 degrees Celsius, while glycerol has a boiling point of 290 degrees Celsius.

I do not know whether or not heating the mixture to 300 degrees would cause a bad reaction or not. But you could try a small scale distillation and find out.